# Postfix Centos7

Tags: email, postfix, email-server, configuration, centos7

I have 2 domains used hosted in same server.

Eg: Domain A and Domain B

Domain A used Google Apps mail server

Domain B used server email(using postfix)

I can send email from Domain B to gmail accounts, and can receive from Domain A as well as gmail accounts. But the email send from Domain B is not received in Domain A.

As Domain A uses External email, i deactivated "Activate mail service on this domain" In mail log getting below message

---

Oct 24 23:16:50 ns532829 postfix/smtp[19312]: 4A9E1538047A: to=, relay=none, delay=139198, delays=139168/0.01/30/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to mail.domain.com[XXX.XX.XX.XXX]:25: Connection timed out)

if i activate "Activate mail service on this domain " on Domain A then error will be like "Recipient address rejected: User unknown in virtual mailbox table"

Kindly help!Thanks in advance!

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases, hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/aliases
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command = PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
disable_vrfy_command = yes
home_mailbox = Maildir/
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mail_owner = postfix
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mailman_destination_recipient_limit = 1
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
message_size_limit = 1024000
mydestination =
mydomain = domainB.com
myhostname = mail.domainB.com
mynetworks = 168.100.189.0/28, 127.0.0.0/8
myorigin = $mydomain
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
plesk_virtual_destination_recipient_limit = 1
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/README_FILES
relay_domains =
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/samples
sender_dependent_default_transport_maps = hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/sdd_transport_maps
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
smtp_send_xforward_command = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_use_tls = no
smtpd_authorized_xforward_hosts = 127.0.0.0/8 [::1]/128
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated
smtpd_milters = , inet:127.0.0.1:12768
smtpd_proxy_timeout = 3600s
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noplaintext
smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_sender_access hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/blacklists, permit_sasl_authenticated
smtpd_timeout = 3600s
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/pki/XXXX.pem
smtpd_tls_ciphers = medium
smtpd_tls_exclude_ciphers = aNULL
smtpd_tls_key_file = $smtpd_tls_cert_file
smtpd_tls_mandatory_ciphers = medium
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2,!SSLv3
smtpd_tls_protocols = SSLv3, TLSv1
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_use_tls = yes
tls_medium_cipherlist = HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5
transport_maps = , hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/transport
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
virtual_alias_maps = $virtual_maps, hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/virtual
virtual_gid_maps = static:31
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/qmail/mailnames
virtual_mailbox_domains = $virtual_mailbox_maps, hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/virtual_domains
virtual_mailbox_limit = 0
virtual_mailbox_maps = , hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/vmailbox
virtual_transport = plesk_virtual
virtual_uid_maps = static:30
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: tls_ssl_options=NO_COMPRESSION
```

Comment: If Domain A is using gApps, why is Postfix trying to connect to `mail.domain.com` to deliver?  You appear to be missing rather a lot of important information from your question.

Comment: that is why i am also confused. intead of taking the google apps postfix trying to deliver it locally, i doubt whether it is causing as both domains are on same server

May you please help me to get the correct configuration of postfix in this case

Comment: Edit your postfix configuration into the question, then we can take a look at what might be wrong.

Comment: i have added the configuration

Comment: any luck on this ?